# Scala: List.forall using while loop

Tags: scala

I see following implementation in List.scala from Scala library:

```
override final def forall(p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
    var these: List[A] = this
    while (!these.isEmpty) {
      if (!p(these.head)) return false
      these = these.tail
    }
    true
  }
```

This method can be implemented recursively to get rid of var and while loop.
Reading through all available books,blogs, articles etc online etc, I am under impression that we are supposed to follow recursive approach as much as we can in Scala.

Comment: Standard library is allowed all "sins of Scala programming".

Comment: The stdlib was not intended and should never be considered a good example of FP code. There are multiple reasons why the stdlib is like that, including the preference of their authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mutability of `var these` is not visible outside `forall` method and likely helps with performance

```
override final def forall(p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
  var these: List[A] = this
  ...
  true
} // var is out-of-scope at this point
```

so technically `forall` is still pure from perspective of callers. *Tail* recursive approach would also probably have similar performance as var+while though.

Comment: Yeah, var is only limited to method body. What happens is that those new to Scala and trying to follow all FP principles get confused at such points, particularly when we see such code in Scala's standard library, and may gradually start doing this in our application code too. I wonder if Haskell allows such code in its standard library.

Comment: @Mandroid: Haskell's standard library aggressively uses performance-optimized code as well. In fact, I don't know *any* programming language where the standard library is written in idiomatic, high-level code. (If only for the obvious reason that you *need the standard library for that in the first place*.) Pretty much all of them are aggressively performance-optimized. Heck, many aren't even written *in the same language*. E.g. Large parts of CPython's standard library are written in C, same for YARV, same for PHP, same for V8. Even the Oracle JRE contains a fair amount of native C++.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive approach is considered more declarative and readable that's why it's a good approach. From the other side functional approach implies immutibilty in particular which can lead to perfornace degradation so using such approach in Scala library is understandable.  I assume that the authors of the Scala library didn't assume users heavily read their code as it's should be under the hood.